# Meta viewport tag user scalable=no ignored in Android 6.0+, Chrome version 53?

Tags: android, html, google-chrome, viewport, meta-tags

I have created a responsive website, that should scale accordingly to the window size. The website provides a drawing app (with mouse/finger) that has its own zooming libraries so I don't want to allow the user to scale the page with the classical "pinching" because that will mess with my libraries and create an offset.

So I added the meta viewport tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1">
```

Which should not allow the user to scale by pinching. But it does.

Android v 6.01, Chrome v. 53 completely ignores the **user-scalable=no** while on Firefox v.48 it works as supposed (or at least as I think it's supposed). could not test on safari because I don't have an iOS device handy.

**LATER EDIT:** Android v 6.01, Chrome v. 52 doesn't allow pinching when **user-scalable=no**.

What did I do wrong here? Is the user-scalable property ignored by default in the latest version of Chrome?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably have "Force enable zoom" checked in Settings>Accessibility. user-scalable=no works correctly for me in Chrome M53.

Comment: Yep, you are right. I wouldn't have been to figure that out for the love of God. Now that I think of, what a dumb question to ask

Comment: @Roxanne Great question to ask, it just solved my problem too.

Comment: Just to note, this is `Settings -> Accessibility` in *Chrome*, not Android.  However, in this case I don't have "Force enable zoom" enabled, yet it still isn't honoring the `user-scalable=no` directive.  Android 8.1, chrome 67.